# Join two queries on the exact same column into one result table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
INSERT INTO COLOR
SELECT 'COLOR', 'RED'
UNION
SELECT 'config', 'RED'
UNION
SELECT 'CONFIG_VALUE', 'RED'
UNION
SELECT 'XYZ', 'BLUE'
UNION
SELECT 'TEST', 'BLUE'
UNION
SELECT 'COLOR', 'BLUE'
UNION
SELECT 'COLOR', 'RED'
UNION
SELECT 'COLOR', 'BLUE'
UNION
SELECT 'COLOR', 'RED'
```

I would like to run two queries on the same column, to get a result table that has a count of how many blue and red items there are - blue as the title for one column, and red being the title of the second column.

I have the two separate queries returning the count for each one, but when I join these with a union it turns out strange.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what do you want. Please illustrate with sample example and expected result. Please also show your current query

Comment: Table is as I sent it, and I would like the result to be like this:

--------
blue  red
4          5

so this is one table as the result, with two independent columns - blue, and red. And the value for each column, the only row, is the number of instances of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when color = 'BLUE' then 1 else 0 end) as blue,
       sum(case when color = 'RED' then 1 else 0 end) as red
from t;
```